# Android - release memory on calling finish() in activity

Tags: android, android-activity, memory, out-of-memory, activity-finish

On calling finish() for closing activity, objects within the activity is not released from memory in Android

**Case**:
Activity A opens Activity B and on finish() of Activity B , Activity B is closed however memory is still occupied as such, on calling Activity B again from Activity A, Android allocates more memory finally resulting in Out of Memory Error.

**Workaround:**
using System.exit(0) after finish() in Activity B releases memory, but it shows a blank white screen on returning to previous Activity A. I feel this is not the ideal way.

Appreciate help on resolving this issue for releasing memory on finish() of an Activity.

Comment: Without knowing what A and B actually do, there is no way of answering this question.  Show the source code.

Comment: Seem like you have a memory leak here.

Answer (score 1):

When calling finish() on an activity, the method onDestroy() is executed. So override that method and make all your strong ref variable to null like bitmaps, connections etc.
 And remember onDestroy() isn't a destructor. so you have to do your own stuff to avoid OOM error.

also look at overdraw debugger to avoid overdrawing on a pixel.

Hope this helps you.